# Change google map location on selectbox change after the map and markers loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drop-down-menu

How to change the Google map location so that another lat and long coordinates are in the center of the google map on selectbox change. The map and markers were already loaded successfully. The only thing to change is to let's say scroll the already loaded map to the proper city when it is chosen from the selectbox.  The coordinates of markers should NOT be changed.

```
<select>
  <option value="1" selected>NYC</option>
  <option value="2">Chicago</option>
  <option value="3">Boston</option>
</select>

<div class="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div><!--the google map is loaded already-->
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the coordinates of the locations of the dropdown city, use them.  If not, you can use the geocoder (if you provide names it recognizes):

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    address = $("#dropdown :selected")[0].text;
    geocodeAddress(address, geocoder, map);
  });
  var address = $("#dropdown :selected")[0].text;
  geocodeAddress(address, geocoder, map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(address, geocoder, resultsMap) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = address;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "<br>" + results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
.map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1" selected>New York City</option>
  <option value="2">Chicago</option>
  <option value="3">Boston</option>
  <option value="4">Palo Alto</option>
  <option value="5">Seattle</option>
</select>
<div id="info"></div>
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <!--the google map is loaded already-->
</div>
```